# How do I prevent using firebase.database() in browser console?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database

I have a security problem with using firebase in javascript. Users can just open the browser's console and type **something like `firebase.database().ref().once("value", (data) => console.log(data.val));`** and get all of the database data. Can I somehow prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it more difficult, but not impossible. Even without access to the SDK loaded into a browser using a known global, a determined user can simply invoke the API endpoints directly, and also through the [public REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database).

If you want security, you should be using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) along with [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/index) to determine who can read and write what data. Security rules are evaluated on the server side, so they are impossible to circumvent.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the configuration of your firebase/database rules. 
You should disable read for unauthenticated users.

It should look something like this:

```
"rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
}
```

Actually, without the implementation of Firebase Authentification, you can access the Firebase database from anything that can run JavaScript, and that includes the browser console.